# Parse complex JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

EDITED WITH LARGER JSON:

I have the following JSON and I need to get id element: **624ff9f71d847202039ec220**

```
results": [
    {
      "id": "62503d2800c0d0004ee4636e",
      "name": "2214524",
      "settings": {
        "dataFetch": "static",
        "dataEntities": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "id": "624ffa191d84720202e2ed4a",
              "name": "temp1",
              "device": {
                "id": "624ff9f71d847202039ec220",
                "name": "282c0240ea4c",
                "label": "282c0240ea4c",
                "createdAt": "2022-04-08T09:01:43.547702Z"
              },
              "chartType": "line",
              "aggregationMethod": "last_value"
            },
            {
              "id": "62540816330443111016e38b",
              "device": {
                "id": "624ff9f71d847202039ec220",
                "name": "282c0240ea4c",
              },
              "chartType": "line",
            }
          ]
        }
    ...
```

Here is my code (EDITED)

```
    url = "API_URL"
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
    print url
    all_ids = []
    for i in data['results']:  # i is a dictionary
       for variable in i['settings']['dataEntities']['variables']:
           print(variable['id'])
           all_ids.append(variable['id'])
```

But I have the following error:

```
        for variable in i['settings']['dataEntities']['variables']:
KeyError: 'dataEntities'
```

Could you please help?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @Cocomosi when you're doing `for fetc in i['settings']:` It's looping through all the keys in `i[settings]`. That's why `fetc['dataEntities']` is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it printing when you `print(fetc)`? If you format the json, it will be easier to read, the current nesting is very hard to comprehend.

`fetc` is a string, not a dict. If you want the dict, you have to use the key.

Try:

```py
url = "API_URL"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
print url
for i in data['results']:
    print(json.dumps(i['settings']))
    print(i['settings']['dataEntities']
```

EDIT: To get to the `id` field, you'll need to dive further.

`i['settings']['dataEntities']['variables'][0]['id']`

So if you want all the `ids` you'll have to loop over the variables (assuming the list is more than one)`, and if you want them for all the settings, you'll need to loop over that too.

Full solution for you to try (EDITED after you uploaded the full JSON):

```py
url = "API_URL"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
print url

all_ids = []
for i in data['results']:  # i is a dictionary
    for variable in i['settings']['dataEntities']['variables']:
        print(variable['id'])
        all_ids.append(variable['id'])
        all_ids.append(variable['device']['id']
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am having     print(json.dumps(i[0]['settings']))
KeyError: 0

Comment: ya, I see that now, I updated my answer, could you provide a larger and formatted snippet of the json?

Comment: done, still have the following error with your solution: KeyError: 'dataEntities'

Comment: give it a shot now

Comment: Thanks but still issue :(     for variable in i['settings']['dataEntities']['variables']:
KeyError: 'dataEntities'

Comment: try printing `i['settings']` in the line before the error, and show me what that looks like. If your json is correct, `i['settings']` should be a dict with a `dataEntities` key

Comment: It's printing a JSON {u'dataFetch': u'static', u'dataEntities': {u'variables': [{u'span': u'inherit', ...

Comment: can you `print(type(i['settings']))`. I assumed the original `json.loads()` would return a python dict and all elements would be python objects but seeing the unicode makes me think that the inner elements might not be... I can clearly see the `dataEntities` key though

Comment: I have <type 'dict'> when printing print(type(i['settings']))

Comment: hmmm.... that is very puzzling then. I'm not sure why `i['settings']['dataEntities']` is throwing the KeyError then... I see the key in your print and it is a dict so it should be accessible

Comment: last thing, try 
`for k, v in i['settings'].items(): print(k, v)`

Comment: Thanks, it's now working I get the "id": "624ffa191d84720202e2ed4a",. How can I get the other id (in device node)?      "device": {
                "id": "624ff9f71d847202039ec220",

Comment: I edited my answer to also pull out the device IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The shared JSON is not valid. A valid JSON similar to yours is:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "settings": {
        "dataFetch": "static",
        "dataEntities": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "id": "624ffa191d84720202e2ed4a",
              "name": "temp1",
              "span": "inherit",
              "color": "#2ccce4",
              "device": {
                "id": "624ff9f71d847202039ec220"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to get a list of ids from your JSON you need a double for cycle. A Pythonic code to do that is:

```
all_ids = [y["device"]["id"] for x in my_json["results"] for y in x["settings"]["dataEntities"]["variables"]]
```

Where my_json is your initial JSON.